# ArcGIS JS - Missing "style" when printing dynamic layer

Tags: arcgis-server, javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Im having an issue trying to get the url of the map being printed with a dynamic layer. WIth just tiled services and basemap it prints just fine.

```
 // USED FOR PRINTING OF MAPS
    function print(map_div_id)
    {
        var printUrl = "http://prodgis.agriculture.purdue.edu:6080/arcgis/rest/services/Utilities/PrintingTools/GPServer/Export%20Web%20Map%20Task/execute";
    printTask = new esri.tasks.PrintTask(printUrl);

    var template = new esri.tasks.PrintTemplate();

    template.format = "JPG";
    template.layout = "MAP_ONLY";
    template.preserveScale = true;

    var params = new esri.tasks.PrintParameters();
    params.map = map[map_div_id];
    params.template = template;

    printTask.execute(params, printComplete);
}
```

My Error I get is

```
0: "Error executing tool.: Layer "prime_soil_map_graphics": Missing 'style' in symbol.↵Failed to execute (Export Web Map).↵Failed to execute (Export Web Map Task)."
```

Any ideas what is happening ?

Here is a JS fiddle to test with just press the print button !

http://jsfiddle.net/YMzfM/1/

Comment: Did you applied any security to REST layer?

Comment: No I did not apply any security to the REST layer

Comment: Are you using something custom for the symbology of layer `prime_soil_map_graphics`?

Comment: No , just regular stuff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The symbol for your polygon from your query task is not valid. While it still works within the API, the print task is less tolerant.

Change this:

```
// Executes after the query ahs been completed
dojo.connect(queryTask, "onComplete", function (results) {
    //QueryTask returns a featureSet.  Loop through features in the featureSet avd add them to the map.
    dojo.forEach(results.features, function (feature) {
        var graphic = feature;
        var symbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol(new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new dojo.Color([102, 255, 230]), 3));
        graphic.setSymbol(symbol);
        map[map_div_id].graphics.add(graphic);
    });
});
```

To this:

```
// Executes after the query ahs been completed
dojo.connect(queryTask, "onComplete", function (results) {
    //QueryTask returns a featureSet.  Loop through features in the featureSet avd add them to the map.
    dojo.forEach(results.features, function (feature) {
        var graphic = feature;
        var symbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol(
          "solid",
          new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol(
            esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, 
            new dojo.Color([102, 255, 230]), 
            3
          ),
          null
        );
        graphic.setSymbol(symbol);
        map[map_div_id].graphics.add(graphic);
    });
});
```

Working JS fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/FtWYs/

Answer (score 0):

You modify

```
var printUrl = "http://prodgis.agriculture.purdue.edu:6080/arcgis/rest/services/Utilities/PrintingTools/GPServer/Export%20Web%20Map%20Task/execute";
```

to

```
var printUrl = "http://prodgis.agriculture.purdue.edu:6080/arcgis/rest/services/Utilities/PrintingTools/GPServer/Export%20Web%20Map%20Task";
```